# how to hold invoke post Action result from jquery while upload images?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery

Uploading file by file is running Correctly in my code sample  but i want to hold post action while entering another data fields 
to enter in my Database from inputs , Text etc.
how to control this from post action or how to hold dragged images into object while press button submit and so goto post Actionresult?

This is Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadFiles(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/TempImages/")) || files !=null)
        {
            string TempPath = Server.MapPath("~/TempImages/");

            foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
            {
                string filePath = Path.Combine(TempPath, file.FileName);
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, ReadData(file.InputStream));
                file.SaveAs(filePath);
            }
        }
        return Json("Successfully Uploaded .");
    }

    private byte[] ReadData(Stream stream)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Update:

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.filedrop.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.filedrop.support.js"></script>
```

```
<h2>File Drag & Drop Upload Demo</h2>

<div id='dropbox'>
<span class="message">Drop images here to upload. <br /><i>(they will only be visible to you)</i></span>
```

Comment: Please share your jQuery client-side code as well.

Comment: sorry i'm trying but something goes wrong when i copy paste it as validation of posting code